# Is it possible to apply a CSS style ONLY if a child class is present?

Tags: html, css

I'm using `AngularJS` and `Cordova` (ionic) in a mobile application project, and everything uses the same `page` perse. Everything is loaded into a single `index.html` file, so the `body, html, ion-view, ion-content` elements are all shared between each "page"/"interface"

Basically, all of my interfaces are set up with a unique identifier:

```
<ion-content id="interface-name">...</ion-content>
```

However, in this interface I need to make sure that the following elements have the following styles:

```
html, body, ion-view, ion-content, .scroll {
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

So that the interface can be fullscreen. This is all fine and dandy, but it's causing issues for my other interfaces not being able to scroll/expand vertically.

Is there a way (using CSS) to only apply a style if a child id/class is present, for example the above style is only applied if `id="interface-name"` is applied to a child element?

Comment: If you just want to apply style to the id="interface-name" then in the css just add #interface-name { content }

Comment: There were lots of discussions on `:parent`, `:has()` or selectors with similar purpose over the past years, and, sadly, just discussions. Here's a post from 5 years ago: https://remysharp.com/2010/10/11/css-parent-selector

Comment: @VictorLuna - That doesn't work, if you read the question, because of the nature of a "fullscreen" page, all of the above elements need to have the hight:100% property.

Answer (score 3):

There is a relatively new pseudo-class `:has()` that allows you to only apply css to an element, if a specific child (or children) is present.

[Link to the mdn web docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has)

For example, you can apply a selector to an element of the class `.list` only, of a child with the class `.list-item` is present:

```
.list:has(.list-item) {
  display: block;
}
```

However, this feature is relatively new, and not all common browsers support that css selector yet: [see the browser-compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has#browser_compatibility)

Answer (score 1):

No. That's the "cascading" part of Cascading Style Sheets. It's a top down approach and you can't go back up the stream.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your code above to work on ID/class, for example apply only to id="interface-name"

```
#interface-name {
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You could do it with a JavaScript function at page load time, but you can't apply CSS rules conditionally on the existence of child elements. Something simple like

```
var parent = document.getElementById("elementId").childNodes;
var children = parent.childNodes;
for(child in children) {
    if(child.id == "theIdYouAreLookingFor") {
        parent.style.height = "100%";
        // set other CSS rules here
        // ...
        break; // we're done, no need to check other children
    }
}
```

Comment: The question specifically asks to do it in CSS.

Comment: I guess the answer is no then :S

Comment: How can I modify the `html` style using javascript?

Comment: There's a few ways but this should be fine: var htmlElement = document.body.parentNode